# async call result provides ranges and command for codelens

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, async-await

[ProvideCodeLens](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CodeLensProvider.provideCodeLenses) states that:

> This call should return as fast as possible and if computing the commands is expensive implementors should only return code lens objects with the range set and implement resolve.

My async network call to my API returns ranges and the info I put in the CodeLens, for example:

```js
[{
      "stenographyResult": {
        "data": "...",
      },
      "startPosition": {
        "row": 9,
        "column": 3
      },
      "endPosition": {
        "row": 11,
        "column": 4
      }
 }]
```

where `startPosition` and `endPosition` are start and end lines of a code block respectively, and `data` is used for command.

This seems to become a blocking call and VSC will stall if this call takes time to return, and causes other functions on VSC like file creation to halt.

If one makes an async call that returns an `array` of `ranges` and commands like above, how can we make this call not stall the entire editor, and ideally use `resolveCodeLens` (but we don't know the ranges **until** the network call finishes)

Relevant code:

```js
public provideCodeLenses(document: vscode.TextDocument, token: vscode.CancellationToken): vscode.CodeLens[] | Thenable<vscode.CodeLens[]> {        
        if (vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().get('stenography.codeLensMode')) {
            ...
                return vscode.window.withProgress({
                    location: vscode.ProgressLocation.Window,
                    cancellable: false,
                    title: 'Fetching from Stenography Autopilot'
                }, async (progress) => {
                    try {
                        progress.report({ increment: 0 });
                        return fetchStenographyAutopilot(STENOGRAPHY_API_KEY!, document.getText(), language, false).then((data: any) => {
                            try {
                                 ...
                                data.code_blocks.forEach((block: any) => {
                                    var firstLine = document.lineAt(block.startPosition.row - 1);
                                    var textRange = new vscode.Range(firstLine.range.start, firstLine.range.end);
                                    let command = {
                                        title: "<stenography autopilot />",
                                        tooltip: block.stenographyResult.pm,
                                        command: "stenography.codelensAction",
                                        arguments: [block.stenographyResult.pm]
                                    };
                                    this.codeLenses.push(new vscode.CodeLens(textRange, command));
                                    this.cache.codeLensCache[filename]!.push({
                                        boundTo: block.stenographyResult.code,
                                        command: command
                                    });
                                });
            
                                return this.codeLenses;
                            } 
                           ...
    }
```

Full file: https://github.com/StenographyDev/autopilot-vsc/blob/main/src/CodeLensProvider.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure why this would cause VS Code to stall but that sounds like it could be a bug. First try confirming that it there are not any long running synchronous operations in your extension that are blocking things. If it still isn’t working, please put together a minimal example that demonstrates the issue and file an issue against vscode.

However the docs are also correct: ProvideCodeLenses needs to return the position data as quickly as possible and this isn’t something you can really work around. Try speeding up the api call as much as possible, or if you can’t, try a different approach. Perhaps you can quickly estimate where the code lenses will show up for example?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Matt! Is `provideCodeLens` a blocking function in itself? As in, while it's calling does it consume resources?

Comment: It could block the extension host if your implementation of `provideCodeLens` triggers a long running synchronous operation. However this generally should not block the UI or freeze the editor